# making a binary search tree throws an exception

Tags: java, binary-tree

others say that for making a binary search tree with an array of `{3,7,1,90,45,67,54,23,...}` it is good to work with `TreeSet`.but my code below will throw an exception and I don't know why? my array list`"array"` contains `100 objects` that each object has `two fields 1)digit 2)name` and I want to make a `BST` with these objects' digit's field.please help me thanks.

```
     TreeSet<Element> set = null;
     set = new TreeSet<Element>();
     for(Element e :array){
         set.add(e);
     }

    Iterator it1 = set.iterator();

    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        Object o1 = it1.next();
        System.out.println(o1);
    }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: OBST.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:542)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:238)
    at OBST.GreedyVersion.<init>(GreedyVersion.java:25)
    at OBST.GreedyVersion.main(GreedyVersion.java:66)
```

which is because of line :  `set.add(e);`

Answer (score 6):

This is a really bad question. In your other question (and here), you say that you have an `{3,7,1,90,45,67,54,23,...}`. But you're declaring your set `TreeSet<Element> set`. So what do you really have? Do you have an array of integers? Or is it an array of `Elements`?

If it's really an array of elements, the error message says exactly what the problem is, your Element class must implement [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your `Element` class does not implement the `Comparable` interface, which is needed by the `TreeSet`.

Implementing the `Comparable` interface on `Element` will force you to implement the `compareTo` method. This will define how objects of type `Element` *rank* against each other. This is needed by the `TreeSet` so that it knows how and where to place each `Element` in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Java only supports sortable elements in a `TreeSet`. To make an element sortable, it has to implement the [`Comparable` interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting that error because the elements you're adding do not implement the Comparable interface. What type of array is it?